# What exactly is a message in a MessageEvent?

Tags: java, netty

I have the requirement of recording (and replaying) UDP packets with netty.

The javadoc for MessageEvent states: "A ChannelEvent which represents the transmission or reception of a message."

In the case of a UDP socket, does this mean that the message always contains the payload of exactly one distinct received UDP packet?

Or are the messages a more abstract concept, in that they can contain only fragments or the payloads of multiple UDP packets.

I am using Netty 3.6.2.Final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the message event will contain the payload of exactly one UDP packet.